# Website wrapped in App - Loading

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm working on an Android App that simply wraps a mobile version of a website inside of a native App container.

At present I call (example):

```
    wv.loadUrl("http://www.websitehere.com/");
```

I have exported the entire project and tested it on my phone and when loading a new page inside of the App it takes a few moments, however not being on a browser there is no loading indicator, so it is a still screen on the current page for a few moments (depending on internet speed) while the new page loads.

What would be the best way to implement a loading indicator so that the user knows that a new page is infact loading?

EDIT: Loading added, but only for the initial pageload of app.

```
    public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Page is", "Loading...",true);
    WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    if(pd.isShowing()&&pd!=null);
    {
        pd.dismiss();
    }
}

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Page is", "Loading...", true);
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
    }
    });
    wv.loadUrl("http://www.websitehere.com");
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start a ProgressDialog before you load the website and dismiss it after the loading is done.

Code should look something like this:

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");
wv.loadUrl("http://www.yourwebsite.com");
progressDialog.dismiss();
```

EDIT: new code for every new url clicked

You should add this to your WebViewClient and also make you (ProgressDialog) pd a member variable.

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Page is:", "Loading...",true);
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}
```

EDIT:

You should make the ProgressDialog pd a member variable.

```
public class Main extends Activity {

private ProgressDialog pd;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Page is", "Loading...",true);
    WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if(pd.isShowing()&&pd!=null);
            {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            pd = ProgressDialog.show(Main.this, "Page is", "Loading...", true);
        }
    });
    wv.loadUrl("http://www.websitehere.com");
}
}
```

EDIT: using onPageStarted.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have implemented something similar however that only works when the app/webpage is initially opened. Once I then load another page within the app the loading indicator does not display.

Comment: Could you post your code with the way you are trying to show the loading indicator right now?

Comment: I have included it in my original question.

Comment: Looks like we are almost there.
At the moment, with that implemented, I receive an error:
        The method show is not applicable for progressdialog arguments

Comment: Added a new implementation, if this doesn't work. Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Gave that a try, still received the same error although I realized I was not calling the activity:
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(Main.this, "Page is",         "Loading...",true);

That removed the error, however after testing it still only shows the loading message when the app is first loaded, and not for all other pages within.

Comment: Perhaps you could use onPageStarted? Will change my answer to it.

Comment: No luck with that, although had to change it from Boolean to Void for onPageStarted

Comment: You should take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835560/how-can-i-add-a-loader-dialog-to-my-webview I tried it and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If your website is html based and not server side (asp/php etc) you could package the website in the app so no internet is required. Downside to this is updating 2 websites.

Alternatively you could add a loading script (javascript) to the website itself.

Comment: It is PHP based so I have to request the pages.